# SchTasks Windows 10 access denied

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I wanted to create a task using SchTasks to run my batch file everyday 11pm this batch file starts a programm and runs a vbs script after the programm started. 
I created following Task:

```
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "MY Task" /TR "C:\Users\User\Folder\Batch.bat" /ST 23:00
```

I changed the start time to see if its working but in the task scheduling there is an access denied error "access denied (0x8007005)

I tried to start the task with higher rights to but no matter what I tried it isn't working. Any tips appreciated

Edit: Finally working but in all honesty.. I don't know why it is working now I did the exact same things like the first times. But now I have a different problem: The batch file is now starting correctly but the vbs.script (which is started trough the batch) isn't working.. Any thoughts on this issue or should I ask an entirely new question?

Comment: @w32sh No, I have an password and I have access to the file